# Can I have back right/middle-click maximise for horizontal/vertical maximise?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, mouse

This was a lovely feature of previous window managers. Sure now I can drag a window to the left or right and it will occupy the full vertical height and half the horizontal width, but what about sideways maximisation, or vertical max. without it having to be half the screen?

Is there any way to restore this functionality?

I'm using Gnome Shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, but you can:

- double-click title bar to maximise horizontally
- middle-click title bar to maximise vertically

Can't be totally sure this isn't something fiddly/hacky I've done in the past, but it works for me!

EDIT: Yes, it was something fiddly: install "Advanced Settings" and then in the Windows bit you can select from a few options of what happens when you click in various ways on the title bars.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can.

Just go to Settings, Keyboard, Shortcuts, Windows and change "Maximize window vertically".

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+↑

Comment: Is this with GNOME? Some screenshots uploaded to http://imgur.com and linked in would help us understand your answer...